# Nissan pathfinder 96

Tags: tires

My front passenger side tire feels like it has a flat, I looked and it's not even low, but there is a spot about12 inches  long that is wore and wires are starting to show. Do I need an alignment? I thought it would be worse all around there if it needed one

Answer (score 1):

Flat spotting can be caused by intensive braking or by having the vehicle towed with the wheel locked by a parking brake. A twelve inch long segment is certainly excessive. If the cords are showing, the tire is unsafe for operation, but the symptoms do not point to alignment issues.

I can't picture any braking situation that would wear that much rubber. The towing aspect is more within reason.

Comment: It hasn't been towed but I did have to have brake lines replaced because of a broken line and spots rusted out in the others. Thank you for your help